# Want to embed my D3.js graph into microsoft powerpoint

Tags: d3.js, activex, embed, powerpoint

I have built a bar graph in D3.js on this webpage: https://www.blackrockblog.com/2015/11/12/how-the-world-retires/

Can we embed this same bar graph on the Microsoft Powerpoint slide as well?

Any answer or thoughts will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Deepanshu

Comment: What do you mean by embed? You could take a screenshot and include the image.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I mean to embed it using the activeX component, which would have the same dynamic effect on the power point slide rather than the static screenshot image. Hope this clears your doubt.